# Delete rows with specific conditions in R

Tags: r, data-wrangling

My data frame is ABC:

```
    C1  C2  C3
L1  38  53  63 
L2  9   44  75 
L3  57  57  96 
L4  41  78  3 
L5  81  39  65 
L6  16  19  97 
L7  13  95  65 
L8  44  28  71 
L9  14  66  66 
L10 6   45  90
```

I want to keep rows that have highest five values in C3, and delete the rest. So, the final output should be:

```
    C1  C2  C3
L6  16  19  97 
L3  57  57  96 
L10 6   45  90 
L2  9   44  75 
L8  44  28  71
```

Should I use if function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `order` :

```
ABC[head(order(-ABC$C3), 5), ]

#    C1 C2 C3
#L6  16 19 97
#L3  57 57 96
#L10  6 45 90
#L2   9 44 75
#L8  44 28 71
```

---

In `dplyr`, you can either use `top_n` :

```
library(dplyr)
ABC %>% top_n(5, C3)
```

Or `arrange` and `slice`

```
ABC %>% arrange(desc(C3)) %>% slice(1:5)
```

**data**

```
ABC <- structure(list(C1 = c(38L, 9L, 57L, 41L, 81L, 16L, 13L, 44L, 
14L, 6L), C2 = c(53L, 44L, 57L, 78L, 39L, 19L, 95L, 28L, 66L, 
45L), C3 = c(63L, 75L, 96L, 3L, 65L, 97L, 65L, 71L, 66L, 90L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", 
"L6", "L7", "L8", "L9", "L10"))
```

Comment: Hey Ronak. It's you again! Thank you so much for giving me those great options, and perfectly work!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `filter()` in dplyr, like;

```
library(dplyr)
data("iris")

# filter sepal.length greater than 1
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  filter(Sepal.Length>1)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 150 x 5
# Groups:   Species [3]
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa
```

Comment: Thank you mnm for giving me your opinion!